# Matlab pass variable from one callback to another

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am new to matlab and I want to pass one variable to another :

Here is callback 1 where I write variable with input :

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

c = {'Enter image size:'};
title = 'Input';
dims = [1 35];
definput = {'500'};
answer = inputdlg(c,title,dims,definput);
disp(answer);
b = str2double(answer); // I want to pass this b to other callback
disp(b); 
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And here I got another callback where I want that variable **b** would be my **c** :

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

 h = randi([0 70],c,c); //here I want that c would be my b from another callback
    dlmwrite('myFile.txt',h,'delimiter','\t');


    [file,path] = uigetfile('*.txt');
    fileID = fopen([path,file],'r');
    formatSpec = '%d %f';
    sizeA = [c c];
    A = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec,sizeA);
    fclose(fileID);

    disp(A);
    image(A);
    saveas(gcf,'kazkas.png')
    %uiputfile({'*.jpg*';'*.png'},'File Selection');
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are halfway there with your `guidata(hObject, handles);`. You can use the `handles` structure to store data, like this:

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    % [...] your code
    handles.b = b;              % Store b as a new field in handles
    guidata(hObject, handles);  % Save handles structure
```

Now you can access `handles.b` from your `pushbutton1_Callback`:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)     
    c = handles.b;
    % [...] your code
```

More info on [guidata()](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) and [handles](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/47189-purpose-of-guidata-hobject-handles).

Comment: I find this very unelegant to read and sort of unintuitive from Mathworks. Thanks for this

Comment: Maybe you'll find it more readable to use `setappdata()`  which can [Store application-defined dat](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)